# startactivityforresult() on external Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two Applications, A and B, both applications are made by me but they are in different packages. I want to extract some data from my Activity B to my Activity A.

For this I use `ActivityA.startactivityforresult(ActivityB)`.

This works ok, up until I need to retrive my data from ActivityB, then I start getting NullpointerExceptions for my getExtra() calls.

**ActivityA:**

```
protected void someMethod()
{
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("some.package.app");
    intent.putExtra("action", "retrieveData");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 7854);
}

protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "test: " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
}
```

**ActivityB:**

```
protected void onResume ()
{
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getString("action").equals("retrieveData"))
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("test", "This is a test response");

        setResult(7854, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

---

`OUTPUT: test: null`

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not allowed?

**UPDATE**

```
04-18 18:28:34.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7854, result=0, data=null} to activity {dk.rasive.testA/dk.rasive.testA.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 18:32:48.892: E/AndroidRuntime(15801):    at dk.rasive.testA.TestActivity.onActivityResult(TestActivity.java:245)
```

Line 245 contains this code

```
Log.d(TAG, "test: " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried with Activities in different Applications but Activity A needs to override

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Also

```
setResult
```

takes a ResultCode not a RequestCode although that won't make a difference in the snippet you posted.

EDIT:

androidmanifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityB"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name='retrieveData'/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I just stripped out the @Override annotations for readability´s sake.

Comment: Activity A must override `onActivityResult`.  I didn't say anything about you missing @Override.

Comment: Aha I see :) That solved the problem partially. Now I am getting a: `Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7854, result=0, data=null}` Runtime Exception though.

Comment: Can you post the complete LogCat?

Comment: It doesn't provide a stacktrace, but I updated by question with the one liner it returns.

Comment: Am I correct that that `Failure...` appears when `onActivityResult` is executed?

Comment: Yes that is indeed what happens.

Comment: Are these two activities in seperate applications? ie different apks.

Comment: Yes. Hence why I ask if what I am trying to do is even allowed.

Comment: It is possible because for example you can write an app that launches the built-in camera app and grab its picture.  Also the RequestCode is being passed ok.

Comment: Unless I have to use it any other places than I already specified in the question, then yes.

Comment: Have you tried setting an intent filter with an action on Activity B and remove the `getLaunchIntentForPackage`?

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't, could you post another answer with an example, since I don't really know what it would look like in my manifest.

Comment: You are welcome.  Many thanks for the votes.  Oh forgot to say use `Intent.setAction` but you obviously worked that out ;)

Comment: @techiServices, I think it is better to add what you said about setAction to the answer, because it is more convenient and not all people read comments especially when they are so much :) Thanks.